# Using recursion to add 0 after every even digit

Tags: java, recursion

**Hello guys,**

I would like to share with you my problem. I am practicing recursive methods and i have noticed somewhere one exercise. The exercise is about making the recursive method which adds a 0 to every even digit. If someone has some idea, it would be great if you share here.

---

**the code would be something like this :**

```
public static String adding0AfterEvenNumber(int number) {

    String s = String.valueOf(number);
    String result;
    if (number < 10 && number % 2 == 0) {
        return s + 0;
    }
}
```

I am missing the main part of the code but i really do not have an idea how to create it. Thanks in advance

---

Comment: Are you trying to replace the value with a zero or append a zero? Example : should 2 become 20 or 0? Simply adding zero would not change the value.

Comment: suppose the recursive calling part of the code is missing in the shred code.

Comment: And it seems like you don't need to deal with negative numbers and integer overflow?

Comment: @DonPeat  to append dude, just like your example. 2 should become 20

Comment: @Jedi its not necessary but it could be the part of a method.

Comment: There are so many questions... why `String` as a return type if we were supposed to work on numbers? How would you like to implement recursion here? There is no need for it. Multiplying by 10 is just a single operation. It's really unclear what you are asking for/about.

Comment: do not forget a recursive function makes one or more calls to itself ... the code you show is not calling itself so is not recursive

Comment: @ScaryWombat I was working on a project so i have totally forget to check the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

consider this code (comments in line)

```
 // somewhere to store the result
 static StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

 public static void main(String [] args) {

     // starting string
     String s = "1234567";
     // or as 
     //String s = Integer.toString(1234567);

     // call with full string
     recurse (s);

     // print result
     System.out.println("result : " + result.toString());
}

private static void recurse(String s) {

    // take first char and add to result
    String c = s.substring(0,1);
    result.append(c);

    // see if even, note no error checking for is a number
    if (Integer.parseInt(c) % 2 == 0) {
        result.append("0");
    }

    // then if still has content then strip off first char and call again
    if (s.length() > 1)
        recurse(s.substring(1));

}
```

**output**

result : 1203405607

Comment: Nice and fast, though OP's original signature requires an int input and a String return value.

Comment: @Jedi Based upon the OP code, I am not sure that the method signature is required *something like this*  The benefit of this way is that it can take a huge number

Comment: @ScaryWombat It works fine dude and i will never get idea to work with StringBuilder. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I did it  bro  @ScaryWombat

Answer (score 2):

You would recurse something like this:

```
public static String adding0AfterEvenNumber(int number) {
    return ((number >= 10) ? adding0AfterEvenNumber(number / 10) : "") + String.valueOf(number % 10) + ((number % 2 == 0) ? "0" : "");
}
```

Try it [here](https://repl.it/JDEV/1).

```html
<script src="//repl.it/embed/JDEV/1.js"></script>
```

The first part is the terminal condition, appending nothing if there is a single digit number, else calling the recursion after removing the last digit:

```
(number > 10) ? adding0AfterEvenNumber(number / 10) : "")
```

The second part appends a zero to the last digit, if even:

```
String.valueOf(number % 10) + ((number % 2 == 0) ? "0" : "")
```

Comment: Thanks bro, it is working. I have been outside so i could not answer you earlier. I really like your idea to appending nothing so thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I understand that even digits are those digits with an even value not in an even position. The following function should return you a string with the value, although you could return an integer if you shift the head value as many digits as the tail has.

```
    public String add0onEven(int number, int initPos, int endPos) {
    if (initPos == endPos - 1) {
        int digit = (number / (int) Math.pow(10, initPos)) % 10;
        if (digit % 2 == 1) {
            return digit + "0";
        } else {
            return "" + digit;
        }
    } else if (endPos - initPos < 1) {
        return "";
    } else {
        int sepIdx = (endPos - initPos) / 2 + initPos;
        String tail = add0onEven(number, initPos, sepIdx);
        String head = add0onEven(number, sepIdx, endPos);
        return head + tail;
    }
}
```

You can call the method like this:

```
add0onEven(1234567, 0, 7)
```

The output obtained for this invocation:

```
10230450670
```

I believe this solution to be better than the substring ones for its lower impact on memory (No need to create a new string on each substring invocation). Besides,  it follows a Divide and Conquer approach that suits better to recursivity.